# How to compare table column name as column value in Inner Join query In SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
SELECT 
    T1.AwardDatePlanned, T1.AwardDateActual,
    T2.ProjectMileStoneId
FROM 
    #TempTbl1 T1 
INNER JOIN 
    TempTbl2 TP ON T2.ExternalName = (Here I want to use T1.AwardDatePlanned column name as value to compare with T2.ExternalName)
```

In my `TempTbl2` table, I have `ExternalName` as `AwardDatePlanned,AwardDateActual`.

Let me know if someone can help me for solve this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Trying to  match current stored values from a table to database objects (like column references) can only be done with dynamic SQL, and be very careful about SQL injection.

Comment: You can use a string literal `ON T2.ExternalName ='AwardDatePlanned'`

Comment: you could get the column names from sys.columns `SELECT * FROM   tempdb.sys.columns WHERE  object_id = Object_id('tempdb..#TempTbl1'); `

Comment: I would suggest you have a design flaw somewhere, but it's hard to say without the full schema